# How to apply border to an exported file?

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

I am using this code for exporting the excel file. it works fine.

```
public void WriteHtmlTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> data, TextWriter output)
{

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            Table table = new Table();
            TableRow row = new TableRow();
            PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
            {
                TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                cell.Text = prop.Name;
                row.Cells.Add(cell);
            }

            table.Rows.Add(row);


            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                row = new TableRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in props)
                {
                    TableCell cell = new TableCell();
                    cell.Text = prop.Converter.ConvertToString(prop.GetValue(item));

                    row.Cells.Add(cell);

                }

                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }

            table.RenderControl(htw);  
            output.Write(sw.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

and gives me this output
[image]

but output which 
I want is this[image]

I want border for all rows and columns.what changes do I need to make in my code??
thanks in advance...

Comment: By writing a real Excel file, not outputting HTML and calling it Excel. Or if you really must, you can probably do so by applying the proper CSS.

Comment: I am outputing html and then calling the excel file in jquery

Comment: Yeah that's nice. HTML is not Excel.

Comment: yea.but What I want is to apply a css for my html data

Comment: How can it be possible??

Comment: Is your question _"How to apply CSS to an HtmlTextWriter"_? Then search the web for that.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. Though I have not tested the code but you can do something like

```
//Add Borders for All Cells
            sheet.Range["A1:E9"].Style.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeTop].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
            sheet.Range["A1:E9"].Style.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeRight].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
            sheet.Range["A1:E9"].Style.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeLeft].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
            sheet.Range["A1:E9"].Style.Borders[BordersLineType.EdgeBottom].LineStyle = LineStyleType.Thin;
```

Note: Reference https://janewdaisy.wordpress.com/2011/12/05/c-add-borders-for-cells/